# About the coefficients generated by Extended Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I double-checked and tested my statement, and found that I missed several constraints. Sorry for the inconvenience caused!

Let $$
\begin{aligned}
&r_0:=a,r_1:=b,r_{i+1}:=r_{i-1}\bmod r_i\\
&q_i:=\left\lfloor \frac {r_{i-1}}{r_i}\right\rfloor\\
&s_0:=1,s_1:=0,s_{i+1}:=s_{i-1}-s_iq_i\\
&t_0:=0,t_1:=1,t_{i+1}:=t_{i-1}-t_iq_i\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Then, **if $a>b$**, do we necessarily have
$$
\forall s,t,i(s,t\in\mathbb{Z}, |t|\le |t_i|,st\not=0,i\ge 2),|sa+tb|\ge |s_ia+t_ib| 
$$
I confirmed this with several examples, but I don't know how to prove(or disprove) it.

Here is the testing program, and it seems to be fine.

```
from random import randint
LIM=5000

def ExtendedEuclidean(a,b):
    r,s,t=[a,b],[1,0],[0,1]
    lam=0
    while r[lam+1]!=0:
        lam+=1
        r.append(r[lam-1]%r[lam])
        s.append(s[lam-1]-s[lam]*(r[lam-1]//r[lam]))
        t.append(t[lam-1]-t[lam]*(r[lam-1]//r[lam]))
    return lam,r,s,t

def Test(a,b):
    lam,r,s,t=ExtendedEuclidean(a,b)
    print("Testing for a=%d b=%d" % (a,b))
    for i in range(2,lam+2):
        print("r[%d]=%d s[%d]=%d t[%d]=%d:" % (i,r[i],i,s[i],i,t[i]))
        for _s in range(-LIM,LIM+1):
            for _t in range(-t[i],t[i]+1):
                if abs(_s*a+_t*b)<r[i] and abs(_s*a+_t*b)!=0:
                    print("    ",r[i],abs(_s*a+_t*b),_s,_t)
                    sys.exit(0)

for a in range(1,100):
    for b in range(0,a):
        Test(a,b)

while True:
    a=randint(2,500)
    b=randint(1,a-1)
    Test(a,b)
```

Comment: This is probably closely related to the fact that the Extended Euclidean Algorithm finds the point on the line $ax+by=d$ that is closest to the origin.

Comment: Thanks, but I am unable to find any materials related to this fact... Can you give me some links to refer to(if it's not too much work for you)?

Comment: I don't get it. For $i = 1$, your claim says that $\left|sa+tb\right| \geq \left|b\right|$ for $-1\leq t\leq 1$. But this isn't true in general, is it?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I wasn't careful enough when presenting my statement. Now I added some constraints along with my testing program. Hope this will work. Sorry!